# Unit Testing WPF UserControls

Tags: multithreading, unit-testing, nunit

Is it possible to test my WPF UserControls from NUnit (or similar)? If I create an instance of the usercontrol in a unit test like so:

```
// Create an instance of the WPF UserControl
var view = new ChildrenListView();
```

I get the following error:

```
"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this"
```

I get the feeling I'm missing something very important here.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [[STAThread]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

```
    [Test]
    [STAThread]
    public void TestConstructorDoesNotThrow()
    {
        Expect(() => new ChildrenListView(), Throws.Nothing);
    }
```